# Open already created window from within another window

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium

In my app.js file I've created a window called login_window.

I have a window called win1 which has my basic app functions. In there, I have a Logout button. When clicked, I'd like to have it open the login_window. Can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: windows? do you mean you wanna use 2 UIWindow in a single app?

Comment: @meronix The OP is using Titanium.

Answer (score -1):

*Use this:*

login_window *vc = [[login_window alloc] init];

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[vc logOutPressed:(id) sender];